# Javascript to convert milliseconds to time

Tags: javascript

I have this code

```
<script>
function msToTime(Milliseconds)
    {
        var Hours = Milliseconds / (1000*60*60);
        var Minutes = (Milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) / (1000*60);
            var Seconds = ((Milliseconds % (1000*60*60)) % (1000*60)) / 1000;
              return Hours + ":" + Minutes + ":" + Seconds;
    }
var xtime=d1.getTime();
    alert(xtime);
    alert(msToTime(xtime));
</script>
```

and it gives me this output
the milliseconds alert which is proper

[image]

Next alert I get this which is wrong:

[image]

Whats wrong with the code?

Comment: Hours should additionally be `% 60`'d

Comment: The best way to understand what's going wrong is to put the intermediate values in temporary variables and walk through the code in the debugger.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't use the `Date` object for this task?

Comment: use parse keyword in javascript check it from google.

Comment: what is d1 here in d1.getTime();

Comment: ok i will check using date object

Comment: I only want the time not the date

Comment: `var dateInst = (new Date(d1.getTime()))` would convert milliseconds back to the corresponding date. Then you can use `dateInst.toLocaleTimeString()` to get just the time

Comment: there is nothing wrong with the code, or with the output, this is the number of hours elapsed since 1970...

Answer (score 2):

Let the standard library do the work for you ;-)

```
function msToTime(Milliseconds)
    var d = new Date(Milliseconds);
    return [d.getHours(), d.getMinutes(), d.getSeconds()].map(function (v) {
        return v < 10 ? '0' + v : v;
    }).join(':');
}
```

Comment: this works.But seconds comes in single digit.I guess that wont be a problem.Thnx

Comment: Add something like `v < 10 ? '0' + v : v`... actually combining several functions is very basic coding technique

Comment: Since we use map from `es5`, this one-liner would be simpler if time is guaranteed to be within one day: `new Date(Milliseconds).toJSON().slice(11, -5)`

Answer (score 2):

Try this :

```
function msToTime(ms) {
    var d = new Date(ms);
    return (
        ("0" + d.getHours()).slice(-2)
    ) + ":" + (
        ("0" + d.getMinutes()).slice(-2)
    ) + ":" + (
        ("0" + d.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    ); 
}
```

It will return time in format `HH:MM:SS`.

**EDIT :**
`().slice(-2)` method return last two digit number after appending `0` in front.
for e.g if value is `045` second than it will return `45` second value and if second value is `07` than it will return `07`value.
It work to pick only last two digit from the value to make it two digit value even though value is less than 10.

[Reference Link](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_slice_array.asp)

Comment: +1 for cool `('0' + v).slice(-2)`, I use it too... but with array (like in my solution) you'd be able to use `map` and that way it would be cooler.

Comment: @kirilloid Personnaly, I usually don't advise to use `map` since it's not supported by IE8 and lower. If I do it anyway, I warn the OP about that and provide a workaround like this one : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map#Polyfill.

Comment: purpose of using `('0' + v).slice(-2)` is to make your value duble digit.

Comment: @wared description added in answer.